# Action on ActionBar doesn't show

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Yesterday I had a problem with replacing fragments, so I had to change my `MainActivity` to extend `Acivity` instead of `ActionBarActivity` in order to avoid compatibility issues. The problem is, that after I've done that, an actionbar item disappeared. I tried following androids official tutorials on how to set it up **without using the support library**, but with no avail. This is what I have:

Inside the `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frag_container, new MainMenuFragment()).commit();
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    return true;};
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

As you can see, I'm implementing the needed methods for the action bar to be populated with buttons. This is my menu's XML file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.pszczyna.MainActivity" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

The manifest is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.jam.pszczyna"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.jam.pszczyna.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

which is the minimum SDK version required for this to work. For me everything looks like it's supposed to, whats wrong with it?

Comment: Did you check if it is in the overflow menu? if it is you can try with `app:showAsAction="always"`

Comment: Did you try with showAsAction:"always" ?

Comment: I just tried, it didn't work.

Comment: What's your theme in `AppTheme`?

Comment: @ShobhitPuri The style AppTheme is empty.

Comment: @jammaster Can you paste the xml in that file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.pszczyna.MainActivity" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

and in your manifest remove `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"` and put your own style.

Comment: I tried changing the showAsAction already, it doesn't work. Also, i have no `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"` in my manifest

Comment: Do you use **android**:showAsAction="always" do you add android prefix

Comment: Wow, completely didn't notice that i have **app**:showAsAction in my file. Nice eye. Thank you for your help!